# How to modify VBA macro to run only on columns of selected cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the macro below to keep cells only in a specified interval and remove the rest (i.e. keep the 1st, 5th, 10th, etc. point in a given column)

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastRow Step 5
   Range(Rows(i), Rows(i+8)).ClearContents
Next i
```

Currently, the macro deletes entire rows on the entire worksheet. I would like to modify the macro I can select the cell at the top of a single column I want to modify and run the macro only on that column.

For example, I have data in, say, A1:B350 and C1:E95 (both on the same sheet). I want to be able to run the macro and keep only a specified interval of cells in columns A-B without disturbing columns C-E. Likewise, I would like to run the same macro in column C without disturbing data in Column A. At this point, I am not sure how to modify this macro to meet this task. I'd greatly appreciate any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will only affect the column you select, but I altered the step from 8 to 12 since otherwise all values were being cleared. Also, the usedRange function may not make sense since now only one column is the focus. Hopefully this code will get you started and you can adjust as needed.

```
Sub delColumnData()
Dim r As Range, col As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long
Set r = Application.InputBox("select column", , , Type:=8)
col = r.Column
Set r = Cells(1, col)
LastRow = r.End(xlDown).row
For i = 2 To LastRow Step 12
   Range(Cells(i, col), Cells(i + 8, col)).ClearContents
Next i
End Sub
```

To handle multiple columns:

```
Sub delColumnsData()
Dim r As Range, col As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set r = Application.InputBox("select column(s)", , , Type:=8)
For j = 1 To r.columns.Count
  col = r(j).Column
  LastRow = r(j).End(xlDown).row
  For i = 2 To LastRow Step 12
     Range(cells(i, col), cells(i + 8, col)).ClearContents
  Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Tony, how can I go about modifying this code to include a range of columns e.g. Columns B-F, A-K, etc.?

Comment: I've now added a second version below the original to handle a range of columns

Answer (score 0):

Another option

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClearColumnValues()
    Dim i As Long, selectedCol As Long

    selectedCol = Selection.Column  'in this case the Selection object can be convenient

    With Application.ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 6
            .Range(.Cells(i + 1, selectedCol), .Cells(i + 5, selectedCol)).ClearContents
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: This is nice and simple code but it deletes the wrong cells. I may have explained this poorly at first. Your code starts at A1 and deletes A2, A7, etc. I am trying to do something that starts at A1, deletes a range of cells, and then keeps the next specified cell. For example Start at A1, delete A2-A6, keep A7, etc.