# Macro to work on selected columns, not set columns (text to number)

Tags: excel, vba

i'm sure this is simple, but i'd like to know how to have a macro work only on a column that is selected (prior to running the macro)

the ultimate goal is to convert text to numbers, but the column these values are in are not always in the same column, without converting the entire workbook, it would only need to convert the selected column.

Comment: `selection.`?..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928426/how-to-modify-vba-macro-to-run-only-on-columns-of-selected-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that works using:

```vb
Sub change_txt_2_number()
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you can try this.

```
a = ActiveCell.Column

Columns(a).Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

Comment: it sounds like this should work, but when I write the macro as:

Sub Text_2_Numbers()
'
' Text_2_Numbers Macro
'

'
a = ActiveCell.Column

Columns(a).Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End Sub



nothing happened when i selected a column with text_Stored_as_numbers, and ran the macro..